# Python script executed from its own directory

Tags: python, windows, directory

If I launch the file `D:\test.py` :

```
f = open('blah.txt','w')
f.write('test')
```

with the command (for example from Windows' **Start Menu > Run**)

```
C:\Python27\python.exe D:\test.py
```

then the file `blah.txt` will be created in `C:\Python27\` instead of `D:\` !

**How to make that the script `D:\test.py` is run from directory `D:\` ?**  (i.e. the output file should be `D:\blah.txt`). **What command should I write in *Start Menu > Run* ?**

Comment: If `.py` is associated with Python, then try `d:\test.py` directly.

Comment: @GregHewgill it is not: `.py` are associated with my editor tool (Notepad++)

Comment: Well, at least that's easy to fix.

Comment: @GregHewgill : No, I don't want to associate `.py` with Python, I want to keep .py associated with my text editor. I would like to find a solution without having to modify my filetype associations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output file being created at the `python.exe` location is the expected OS behavior. When you launch an application this way, its working directory will be set to the directory where the .exe file is located. Python itself will not change the working directory to the script location, so you would have to do that manually. One way is to change the directory in the beginning of your `test.py` script:

```
import os
import sys
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

Another way is to change your "Run" command to something like this:

```
cd /D D:\ && C:\Python27\python.exe D:\test.py
```

This can be put into a batch file unless you like typing a lot :)